# Need To stop Timer counting down when browser tab minimized or been switched between tabs

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my script written
I want to stop timer when user switch to different tabs and resume back when visit the site. can anyone help me to solve this task. Need To stop Timer  counting down when browser tab focus or been switched between tabs can
anyone help me to this code

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <a class="button" href="" id="download">Click To Download</a>

  <button class="infoblogger" id="btn"> Download</button>

  <script>
    var downloadButton = document.getElementById("download");
    var counter = 45;
    var newElement = document.createElement("p");
    newElement.innerHTML = "www.xyz.com";
    var id;
    downloadButton.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, downloadButton)

    function startDownload() {
      this.style.display = 'none';
      id = setInterval(function() {
        counter--;
        if (counter < 0) {
          newElement.parentNode.replaceChild(downloadButton, newElement);
          clearInterval(id);
        } else {
          newElement.innerHTML = +counter.toString() + " second.Please Wait";
        }
      }, 1000);
    };
    var clickbtn = document.getElementById("btn");
    clickbtn.onclick = startDownload
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not as simple as that, if you want to stop the timer and exactly start it at same place. Like if you focus-out tab at half second of `setInterval` and want to start from the same half  second. But if that is not the case for you than you can look into window `blur` and `focus` event

Comment: can u write the lines how to do that in the above code and send me here please I appreciate that work because I'm not from computer science guy I was just looking through YouTube videos and made this far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st :** `<script>` tag is not used inside `div` element

**2nd :** You can use a extra variable and check its state to run the function.
Here used `focusOut` whose value is false, and value changes to true if window minimizes or out of focus(other tab opened) and change back to `false` if gains back the focus. This state is used to keep the function running.

```js
var downloadButton = document.getElementById("download");
var counter = 45;
var newElement = document.createElement("p");
newElement.innerHTML = "www.xyz.com";
var id;
let focusOut = false;
downloadButton.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, downloadButton)

function startDownload() {
  this.style.display = 'none';
  id = setInterval(function() {
    if (!focusOut) {
      counter--;
      if (counter < 0) {
        newElement.parentNode.replaceChild(downloadButton, newElement);
        clearInterval(id);
      } else {
        newElement.innerHTML = +counter.toString() + " second.Please Wait";
      }
    }
  }, 1000);
};

var clickbtn = document.getElementById("btn");
clickbtn.onclick = startDownload

window.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  focusOut = true;
})

window.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  focusOut = false;
});
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <a class="button" href="" id="download">Click To Download</a>
  <button class="infoblogger" id="btn"> Download</button>
</div>

<script>
</script>
```

Comment: really thank u so much it worked to my page now Rana Bhai i appreciate ur kindness